# Bulk Record insert through Spark in Postgres and mysql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I'm having an issue , Whenever I insert a record in postgres DB through spark the record is transfered in around 70-60 sec but when ever I connect to mysql and sends the same record the time is increased to more than 5 min ( > 5 mins )..
The data source is also mysql database from which I am retrieving the record.

Can anyone explain this behaviour , The data retrieval DB is using an IP and for both postgres and destination mysql the DB is localhost.

Here some details :

```
  ar_90200_data = spark.read.jdbc (
     url = jdbc_url, table = "ar90200" ,
     properties=connection_properties)

  ar_90200_data.write.jdbc (
      url = jdbc_url_for_local_mysql,
      table = "ar90200_test_landing",
      mode = "overwrite", 
      properties = connection_properties_for_local_mysql
      )

   ar_90200_data = spark.read.jdbc (
        url = jdbc_url, table= "ar90200",
        properties = connection_properties)

    ar_90200_data.write.jdbc (
       url = jdbc_url_for_pos,
       table = "ar90200_test_landing",
       mode = "overwrite",  
       properties = connection_properties_for_pos
     )
```